# npm-windows-upgrade does not complete

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

I've installed Nodejs and went to upgrade npm, but the process just hangs. Here's what I did:

I opened a Powershell prompt **as administrator**.
I ran the following commands:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

When prompted. I selected the latest stable version of npm and pressed `enter`. The shell prompt looks like this and nothing seems to happen (note: there is a blinking cursor on the line after the last text in the pic):

[image]

Note that this only seems to happen on my work machine.
I have successfully done this on my home machine.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: what is your current `node.js` version?

Comment: @BagusTesa it is v10.3.0

Comment: could you check with ProcessExplorer whether your powershell console spawns `node.js` process that fetch the `npm` -- you might need to use ProcessExplorer to check. easier alternative, better to file an issue to [their github](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade/issues). i suspect its a compatibility issue with the latest `node.js`

Comment: Process Explorer revealed interesting happenings. I suspect I have a problem because my $HOME directory is located on a network share (this is a work PC). It spawns a Node process, which in turn spawns another Powershell process which is almost automatically killed off. Not sure how to proceed. Pretty sure I cannot change the $HOME (not permitted to).

Comment: ahhh, what a peculiar environment. i dont think this issue will be eligible for discussion on github. i'm sorry but perhaps you are on your own..

Comment: @BagusTesa I suspect so as well. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: btw i find some [interesting configs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/10/29/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-a-shared-directory/) that might be a hint to the solution.